# electron-osx-sign is not working

Tags: electron

I'm trying to sign my electron app using electron-osx-sign:

```
electron-packager . $APP --platform=darwin --arch=x64 \
  --out dist \
  --ignore=build \
  --ignore=config/development.json \
  --overwrite \
  --prune \
  --icon=appicon.icns \
  --app-bundle-id="com.example.myapp" \
  --build-version=$BUILD --app-version=$VERSION \

electron-osx-sign "dist/myapp/myapp.app" \
  --identity="$DEVELOPER_KEY"
```

it keeps showing the following error:

```
Command failed: codesign --sign Developer ID Application: XXXXXXXXXX --force dist/myapp/myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework
```

where `Developer ID Application: XXXXXXXXXX` is a valid cert.

My `electron-osx-sign` version is `0.4.4` and `electron-packager` is `8.0.0`

Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling, it seems there are some problems using codesign on macOS 10.12,

Please refer to [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65055#thread-message-204823).

I've also post the solution in [this link](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-osx-sign/issues/132#issuecomment-299716060) on the electron-osx-sign GitHub issue page.